# How can I debug ASP.NET Core 3 source code? No Source Link

Tags: asp.net-core, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to debug through the source code of aspnetcore 3 (3.1.3), concretely through Microsoft.AspnetCore.Authentication and as well the libraries for OpenIdConnect and OAuth. I have done it with Source Link but it is far from being any good.

Does somebody know how to debug through the source code if i clone the aspnetcore github repository using Visual Studio 2019?

It will be for an ASP.NET Core web application:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue?

Comment: This shows you how to debug ASP.NET Core source code:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-debug-asp-net-core-source-code-448544c16473?sk=58f24ef1f6b39d0bd2927cd36dbd690c

Answer (score 0):

> How can I debug ASP.NET Core 3 source code? No Source Link

**Since** you have cloned the project into your local PC, you can just set the source files' path into VS2019 by this function:

**Suggestion**

Open **VS2019**-->open a project->right-click on the solution

[image]

Then choose **Properties**-->**Common Properties**--> **Debug Source Files**--> input the folder path of the sources files(`any cs or other compile files`) which you have cloned into your local area.

[image]

**Also**, set the local pdb files into the [VS Symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#configure-symbol-locations-and-loading-options).